# Create a Swift Dictionary subclass?

Tags: swift, collections

Can I subclass a `Swift` `Dictionary` so that I can pass my custom `Dictionary` to methods that expect an ordinary `Dictionary`?

**Edit**

[In my case, I want my custom `Dictionary` to iterate through its keys in insertion-order.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28633703/9636)

Comment: Ouch. That was a quick -2.

Comment: If you -1'ed this, I'd appreciate a comment about why so I don't make the same mistake again.

Comment: I did not downvote, but If I were to guess It's because you've not provided any code that shows current attempts, or what you've tried up til now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swift dictionaries are structs, not classes, so they cannot be subclassed. Ideally, the methods you're working with would be declared to take an appropriately constrained generic CollectionType (or ExtensibleCollectionType, or SequenceType, depending on the situation), rather than specifically a Dictionary.

If that doesn't work for you for whatever reason, you could subclass NSDictionary instead.

(edit) and as Antonio points out, you can do extension Dictionary { … } to add things to the Dictionary struct, which can replace subclassing in some cases.

Answer (score 8):

The following is a struct conforming to Collection which delegates to a dictionary. It is fairly easy to modify to any needs.

```
public struct MyDictionary<Key: Hashable, Value: MyKindOfValue>: Collection {
    public typealias DictionaryType = Dictionary<Key, Value>
    private var dictionary: DictionaryType

    //Collection: these are the access methods
    public typealias IndexDistance = DictionaryType.IndexDistance
    public typealias Indices = DictionaryType.Indices
    public typealias Iterator = DictionaryType.Iterator
    public typealias SubSequence = DictionaryType.SubSequence

    public var startIndex: Index { return dictionary.startIndex }
    public var endIndex: DictionaryType.Index { return dictionary.endIndex }
    public subscript(position: Index) -> Iterator.Element { return dictionary[position] }
    public subscript(bounds: Range<Index>) -> SubSequence { return dictionary[bounds] }
    public var indices: Indices { return dictionary.indices }
    public subscript(key: Key)->Value? {
        get { return dictionary[key] }
        set { dictionary[key] = newValue }
    }
    public func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        return dictionary.index(after: i)
    }

    //Sequence: iteration is implemented here
    public func makeIterator() -> DictionaryIterator<Key, Value> {
        return dictionary.makeIterator()
    }

    //IndexableBase
    public typealias Index = DictionaryType.Index
}
```

Comment: Is it right for Swift 3? I can't compile it at all. And Yes I have protocol `MyKindOfValue`

Comment: Try now. I added the two more subscripts and indices. It goes through now for me. The original was crashing the compiler (!!) for me as well, but if you look at the errors from the compiler (before it crashes) you can deduce what was missing.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with most of the comments here (you cannot subclass a `Struct`, *by design* it is not a class), you might get the results you want with a custom `Struct` that conforms to `CollectionType` (now renamed `Collection` in Swift 3.0):

```
struct YourCustomDictionary<Key : Hashable, Value>: Collection {

    private var elements = Dictionary<Key, Value>()
    private var keyOrder = Array<Key>()

    //your custom implementation here 
    //including tracking for your dictionary order

}
```

You could overload the subscript method so that it appends the key to the `keyOrder` array. Then provide an iterator that will return `(Key, Value)` tuples in the correct order.

You probably don't even need to conform to `Collection`, but this is a good way to get a lot of functionality for free.

Answer (score 2):

No, dictionaries and arrays in swift are structs, which do not support inheritance. The only way to "personalize" a dictionary is by using extensions.